# Code to Change Next Three cells if the value is changed in first cell

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'clear contents of dependent cells
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Select Case Target.Column
    Case 6  'clear columns G, H and I
      Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), _
        Target.Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents

    Case 7 'clear column H and I
    Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), _
    Target.Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents

    Case 8  'clear column I
      Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End Select
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I have 4 columns which have dependent drop down lists.
I want is when i change the value in first column, the next three columns should get cleared. However, the below code only restricting it to two columns not the third column.

Kindly review and advise how to do that.

Thanks
Salman

Comment: Replace `Range(Target.Offset(0, 1),Target.Offset(0, 2))` with `target.Offset(0, 1).resize(,3)` or in your original code change the second offset to 3.

Comment: Thanks SJR for sorting this issue...